# NWRFCSDK causing issue with Ubuntu 12.10, 13.04 and Mac Mavericks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, ubuntu, saprfc

For our project we want to communicate with SAP and for that we are planning to use following:

`RUBY1.9, sapnwrfc gem and NWRFCSDK`

We have download the Linux x86_64 bit version of NWRFCSDK. As Ubuntu and Mac both works on Linux and Unix base operating system. We have expected that 'nwrfcsdk' will work with the above mentioned OSes.

During installation process we have followed these steps:
`

```
ruby setup.rb config  --with-nwrfcsdk-dir=/usr/sap/nwrfcsdk
ruby setup.rb setup`
```

We are getting various errors. In Ubuntu when we run `ruby setup.rb config` command  it fails.

Whereas in Mac it completes the Config command execution, however it fails on SETUP step and it shows this error

```
setup.rb:658: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
linking shared-object nwsaprfc.bundle
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/sap/nwrfcsdk/lib/libsapucum.so, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/sap/nwrfcsdk/lib/libsapnwrfc.so, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)`
```

We have tried all possible ways and problem is coming with libsap files. Because it creates a `nwrfcsdk.bundle` for ruby which application is not able to load due to failure of libsapucum.so and libsapnwrfc.so

Comment: I don't know much about Ruby, but in the Java world, the "bit count" of the library and the runtime have to match. Are you sure you need the 64 bit library version - have you tried the 32 bit version?

Comment: As my machine is 64 bit and my OS is also 64 Bit so as per my knowledge it should support and work with 64bit sdk version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We got confirmation from the SAP team that they do not support Mac OSX and that is the reason it is not working in Mavericks.
However to make it work in `Ubuntu 32bit` we have got the other installer and that worked perfectly for the Ubuntu.

`NWRFCSDK for 32 bit, SAP RFC SDK 6.40 Linux on IA32 32bit`

I hope this will help others.